# Start service on app install

Tags: android, service, installation

I have a service in my app along with activity classes. I want to start service as soon as app is installed. I have been able to start service on app launch,on device reboot, but not on app install.
Any idea if it is possible and if possible then how it can be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got any answer on this?? Because I am stuck now same situation.. How to start service when App is Installed. Reply me help me if you get any solution.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No solution for this

Comment: Ok then How you achieve this any another solutions...

Answer (score 3):

> Any idea if it is possible

[Upon installation, your app is in the so-called "stopped state"](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#;aunchcontrols) and will remain there until something uses an explicit `Intent` to start up one of your components. Unless your app is a plugin for some other app that will do this, your app will not run until the user taps on the home screen launcher icon associated with one of your activities.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply @CommonsWare.
According to you, is there any workaround to do so? It doesn't have any plugin.

Comment: @seema: "is there any workaround to do so?" -- I sure hope not, as that would be a security flaw.